# A characterization for a space that is similar to locally connected spaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology

Let $X$ be a $T_0$ topological space with the property that there exists a basis $\{O_i\}_{i\in I}$ for $X$ such that for each $J\subseteq I$ the subspace $\bigcap_{i\in J}O_i$ has only finitely many connected components. Clearly such a space is locally connected. I am looking for a characterization for such spaces, any comment is appreciated.

Comment: Why is it locally connected?

Comment: @LSpice, for each  $i$ since $O_i$ has finitely many connected components, $O_i$ is a union of open and connected sets ( of $O_i$ and of $X$). Hence, $X$  has a basis all of whose elements are connected and so $X$ is locally connected.

Comment: The definition seems peculiar to me, because I don't usually have much interest in taking infinite intersections _just_ of basis elements. Do you have an example of a space $X$ with a basis $O$ with this property which _doesn't_ have the stronger property that for each $J \subseteq I$ the subspace $\cap_{i\in J} O_i$ is either empty or connected? For example, if $X$ is a Riemannian manifold and $O$ is the basis of geodesically-convex open balls, then for any $J \subseteq I$, $\cap_{i \in J} O_i$ is geodesically convex and hence empty or connected.

Comment: What is the motivation for being interested in such spaces?  That is to say, what is the context of this question?